# Android method for consistent DateTime formatting across application

Tags: java, android, datetime, timestamp

My application queries a SQLite DateTime string and I'm trying to write a single method than I can use across my application so that DateTime timestamps are formatted consistently. So far I have,

```
public class DateTimeUtils {

    public static String formatDueDate(String queryResponse) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
        Date result = new Date();
        try {
            result = sdf.parse(queryResponse);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Which is used in a situations such as

```
taskViewHolder.mDue.setText(formatDueDate(task.getDue().toString()));
```

I'd like the output to look like `June 27, 20015, 5:30PM`

The raw datetime String takes the form: `2015-08-10T17:28:00.000-04:00`

My problems are currently the resulting timestamp format is incorrect and instead looks like `Sun Aug 02 17:29:03 EDT 2015` and instead of parsing the inputted timestamp, just returns the current datetime.

I believe this is because my formatting is actually throwing an exception and i'm just returning the current `Date()` object. What should I change so that the datetime string is parsed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're creating the Date object outside the try block, you're right, if there is a parsing error, the current date will return. SimpleDateFormat does that work for you in the parse method. You could reduce the possibility of the current date returning by assigning the Date variable to null instead of instantiating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

If you already get an correct Date class, maybe you can generator your special format by Calendar class and StringBuilder class.

Like below:

```
       String[] monthString = new String[12];
       if (monthString[0] == null) {
            // Get month string by android locale
            // The String will like Jule or May ...
            Map<String, Integer> months = Calendar.getInstance().getDisplayNames(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                for (String month : months.keySet()) {
                    if (i == months.get(month).intValue()) {
                        monthString[i] = month;
                        months.remove(month);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTime(result);
      StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(monthString[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
      //spec your format string...
```

Hope this can help you.